# ASP.NET Core MVC Error - Edit Delete Not Working

Tags: asp.net-core, edit

I reverse engineered a table from and exiting database. Then added a controller with all scaffolding for views and context. My table does not have a traditional primary key such as "Id" it has a complex key. However, I do have an Id column which is unique.

When the views got created, the set up was correct. I noticed that the out of the box "Edit, Details and Delete" had action links commented out. I removed the comments and pointed the Model items to the "Id" field.

My "Id" field is a guid but I don't think that is a problem. When I click the edit link on the view, I receive a page not found. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dark)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Lit)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contra)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreateDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreateBy)
                </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dark)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lit)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contra)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreateDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreateBy)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my controller

```
public class RoutePartnersController : Controller

{
    private readonly TraderContext _context;

    public RoutePartnersController(TraderContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    // GET: RoutePartners
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.RoutePartner.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: RoutePartners/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var routePartner = await _context.RoutePartner
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PartnerId == id);
        if (routePartner == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(routePartner);
    }

    // GET: RoutePartners/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: RoutePartners/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,PartnerId,RouteCompany,RouteCode,Dark,Lit,Contra,CreateDate,CreateBy")] RoutePartner routePartner)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            routePartner.PartnerId = Guid.NewGuid();
            _context.Add(routePartner);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(routePartner);
    }

    // GET: RoutePartners/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var routePartner = await _context.RoutePartner.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PartnerId == id);
        if (routePartner == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(routePartner);
    }

    // POST: RoutePartners/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid id, [Bind("Id,PartnerId,RouteCompany,RouteCode,Dark,Lit,Contra,CreateDate,CreateBy")] RoutePartner routePartner)
    {
        if (id != routePartner.PartnerId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(routePartner);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!RoutePartnerExists(routePartner.PartnerId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(routePartner);
    }

    // GET: RoutePartners/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var routePartner = await _context.RoutePartner
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PartnerId == id);
        if (routePartner == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(routePartner);
    }

    // POST: RoutePartners/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
    {
        var routePartner = await _context.RoutePartner.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PartnerId == id);
        _context.RoutePartner.Remove(routePartner);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    private bool RoutePartnerExists(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.RoutePartner.Any(e => e.PartnerId == id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what's wrong. I have a table with 7 columns. Column one is an "Id" column that we use to quickly identify a row. It is NOT the primary key. Columns 2, 3 and 4 are the primary key. Oddly when the scaffolding was generated, the primary key columns were NOT included in the view. This ultimately led to the views not working. Is this a VS 2017 bug?

Comment: After you answer your own question, please mark it as ***Answer***.

Comment: Sorry, new to this forum. I thought I did mark it as Answer.

Comment: Not a problem. We normally search unanswered question to help community. So, you do not want others to read a page long question, and  realize at the end that you have already answered your own question.

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know if I did not do something correct. This forum is extremely helpful.

Comment: There is a check mark left side of this answer. Please kindly check it.

Comment: OK, did it but it told me I need to wait 20 hours.